# SENotifier, a Stack Exchange inbox notifier for Mac OS X

Tags: discussion, inbox

I've put together a [status bar notifier for Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) (inspired by Google Notifier) and I thought I'd ask here to get some feedback on a couple of things.

[image: screenshot]

I've developed this on Lion and am curious about whether it works on previous releases of OS X (or whether this even matters very much, in practical terms). This is my first Mac OS X app ever, so I'm not even sure what issues are important.

Also, it sort of needs an application icon, so if you're feeling inclined, artwork would get you a mention and a link in the About panel!

Any other comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So cool - I will check this out when I'm back in front of a Mac. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Looks great - sounds like you need some Beta Testers tho ;) ;)

Comment: @GregHewgill I've been waiting for such a tool for OSX ever since I saw it for Ubuntu! Thank you!

Comment: I have a draft for the icon… It's nothing impressive, but what do you think? Do you want something more original? http://i.imgur.com/CQFKm.png

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the layout for OpenID-based logins is a bit weird (tested on OS X 10.7.3):

[image: Screenshot]

Just a heads up.

Thanks for your work on this wonderful app!

Comment: Thanks. I noticed this too, but nothing I've been able to do seems to change the look. It's just a totally ordinary OS-provided WebView, so I'm not sure what's going on. I'll keep looking though.

Comment: @GregHewgill That’s weird indeed, as it renders as expected in Safari/WebKit. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about its compatibility with previous versions of Mac OS X, I encountered an error when trying to run the program on my Panther machine. So it does not work on 10.3.9.

Comment: Thanks, I might have predicted that. :) I've tried it on 10.6 so it appears to work there too, but since I've used ARC it's unlikely to work on 10.5 or earlier.